# Dynamic Creating Named DataCache programmatically

Tags: azure-caching

With

```
new DataCache("myCacheName");
```

I can successfully access existing named cached in my managed AzureCacheService.

Using a name which was not created in the management portal raises an DataCacheException telling me that the cache doesnt exist.

Now I want dynamically create a new named DataCaches.

I can't find anything about this in the msdn documentation. Also Neither the DataCache nor the DataCacheFactory api are offering methods for creating

Isn't this supported? Any hints are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently , configuration of named cache related properties within a managed cache (which includes creation of named caches, changing it's properties etc) can only be done via Azure portal from within the 'configure' tab. Doing it programmatically is not supported.